# Wordpress change logo of certain page

Tags: wordpress, header

I am using wordpress and I want to have a different page logo for two certain pages.

I have created a child theme and inside the Functions.php file I have added this code:

```
        <?php

         if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_header_logo_img' ) && is_page(877) || ! function_exists( 'wpex_header_logo_img' ) && is_page(970)) {
        function wpex_header_logo_img() {       

            // Get logo img from admin panel
            $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', false, 'http://amcham2.amcham.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/business-branding-identity.jpg' );

            // If logo URL isn't empty return the logo
            if ( '' != $logo_img ) {
                return $logo_img;
            }

            // Otherwise if logo is empty return nothing
            else {
                return;
            }}}?>
```

I have not manged to change the logo though.. I know someting is wrong in there but I do not know what.

I want to change the existing logo with 
"http://amcham2.amcham.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/business-branding-identity.jpg".
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

This was the original code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_header_logo_img' ) ) {
    function wpex_header_logo_img() {



        // Get logo img from admin panel
        $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', false, 'url' );

        // If logo URL isn't empty return the logo
        if ( '' != $logo_img ) {
            return $logo_img;
        }

        // Otherwise if logo is empty return nothing
        else {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Modify of the logo section in the header.php file (Only the logic, its missing the html code):

```
  if ( is_page(877) ) {
     # Image for this page
  } else if ( is_page(970) ) {
     # Image for this page
  } else {
     # Default logo 
  }
```

by your original function in functions.php file (full response to the problem):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_header_logo_img' ) ) {
function wpex_header_logo_img() {

    if ( is_page(877) ) {
        $logo_img = 'Image path for this page image';
    } else if ( is_page(970) ) {
        $logo_img = 'Image path for this page image';
    } else {
        // Get logo img from admin panel
        $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', false, 'url' );
    }

    // If logo URL isn't empty return the logo
    if ( '' != $logo_img ) {
        return $logo_img;
    }

    // Otherwise if logo is empty return nothing
    else {
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thx for answering.

I changed it into this at header.php

` if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_header_logo_img' ) ) {
 function wpex_header_logo_img() {
  $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', false, 'url' );  if ( is_page(877) ) {
   $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', true, 'http://amcham2.amcham.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/business-branding-identity.jpg' );
  } else if ( is_page(970) ) {
   $logo_img = wpex_option( 'custom_logo', true, 'http://amcham2.amcham.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/business-branding-identity.jpg' );
  }  
  else {return $logo_img; }

 }
} `

with no luck

Comment: Check again my response. I updated it with the function you asked too. That should work with no problems ;)